# OpenMP and wxWidgets in C++, where to omp_set_num_threads?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, openmp

I have got C++ code that is parallelized by means of OpenMP. 
I intend to call this code from a GUI written in C++ using wxWidgets.

Now, when I call `omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());`, say, directly before the parallelized block, this has no effect.

1. Where can I call `omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_max_threads());` or how can I otherwise set the number of threads to be used by OpenMP?
2. Does my call not have an effect because I am within a thread launched by wxWidgets?

I do set the compiler parameters for OpenMP correctly. [This unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888734/problem-with-omp-set-num-threads-called-from-a-winapi-thread) seems to be related.

Comment: How do you know it has no effect? Can you explain how you test it?

Comment: I call `omp_get_num_threads()` in the next line. It returns 1, although `omp_get_max_threads()` returns 8.

Comment: Are you calling that in a parallel section of code? It will always return 1 in a serial section.

Comment: I just realized that all cores are being used and the code does in fact run parallelized. Is it customary in this case to delete the question here? It suggests that there is problem where there is none.

Comment: No - leave the question, it may help other people with the same "problem", it's not an uncommon misunderstanding. I don't think you have enough rep to delete it anyway.

Comment: You should post the answer to your own question (explaining your mistake) in the Answers section, so that it would be clear that this question has been answered.